# Access Local Database from Assembly in SAFE Security

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, assemblies, clr

I'm working on my First CLR Assembly and though a lot of Searching and trial and Error I have gotten it installed on my SQL Server.  I go to call it and I get:

"System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission..."

A some research later and it comes to that I should turn this to External_Access but, here is the kicker the database it is trying to connect to and run SQL for a lookup is the one that its running on.

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189566.aspx SAFE Permission is:

"SAFE

SAFE is the default permission set and it is the most restrictive. Code run by an assembly with SAFE permissions cannot access external system resources such as files, the network, environment variables, or the registry. SAFE code can access data from the local SQL Server databases or perform computations and business logic that do not involve accessing resources outside the local databases.

Most assemblies perform computation and data management tasks without having to access resources outside SQL Server. Therefore, we recommend SAFE as the assembly permission set."

It clearly states that I should be able to connect to my Local SQL Sever Database and access data.  I rather keep this as Safe because all I'm doing is a quick lookup of a Dataset it needs.

Here is what the Connection String looks like:

`Dim sConnectionString As String = "Password=<Password>;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=<User>;Initial Catalog=<Database>;Data Source=<Server>;"`

It has to be something simple I'm doing wrong so all this to get to the Question.

How do I access the local Database from a CLR Assembly in the Safe permission context?

Comment: I was right it was a something simple.  The bit of Code above was the right place.

'Dim sConnectionString As String = "Context Connection=true"'

That lets you access your local database in SAFE Mode.  Sort of a bugger to dig out.

Answer (score 1):

I was right it was a something simple.  The bit of Code above was the right place.

'Dim sConnectionString As String = "Context Connection=true"'

That lets you access your local database in SAFE Mode.  Sort of a bugger to dig out.